# Connect to SFMC accounts via REST API with Username and Password - Not Key

Tags: rest-api, api, content-builder

I work at a software company that pushes emails from our app into SFMC. We were using the old SOAP API to connect to client accounts previously, but this is being deprecated and we need to push to Content Builder now.

I don't see how to publish content to Content Builder with only clients username and password to access the API (as opposed to a client secret or key). We have a secret and client key for our app as a whole, but not for each individual account.

I've scoured the documentation for this to no avail. Is there an SDK or public API Client I can leverage?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'll have to create an App in each Business Unit (BU) where you need to work with the API for Content Builder.  Each of those apps will have their own clientID and clientSecret.  You'll have to create a system to generate authentication tokens every hour for each app/BU.  Then you'll use the correct Authentication Token for the corresponding BU where you are manipulating Content Builder assets.

Here's the documentation for creating an API Integration Installed Package for each BU, and how to use that to generate Authentication Tokens which you use in the actual REST API calls for Content Builder.  This URL has the links that are the most straightforward:
https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.noversion.mc-getting-started.meta/mc-getting-started/mc-dev-setup.htm

Once you have the Access Token, you'll use it in the headers of your REST calls like this:

```
GET https://www.exacttargetapis.com/platform/v1/endpoints
Accept: application/json
Authorization: Bearer YOUR_ACCESS_TOKEN
```

The Content Builder REST API documentation can be found here:
https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.noversion.mc-apis.meta/mc-apis/content-api.htm

Keep in mind that anything you're creating in Shared Folders within Content Builder should happen at the top-level (Enterprise) BU.

Comment: This is very useful. The old SOAP api could leverage the un/pw and I was hoping we could continue to leverage it as well. Thanks for the assistance.

Comment: Ya, it's why I prefer the SOAP API over REST... One un/pw to rule them (BUs) all, vs having to manage clientID/Secret to generate tokens for each BU.  Some accounts have hundreds of BUs, which makes REST a sad ordeal.